# In Android (on JB), how can I add an action to a custom rich notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been playing with the new rich notificaitons in Jelly Bean, and everything works as expected when I set up a new notificaiton using the templates `Notification.BigPictureStyle`, `Notification.BigTextStyle`, or `Notification.InboxStyle`. I can use the `Notification.Builder.addAction()` method, and the action buttons show up at the bottom of the extended notification. But when I try to create a cutsom notification using [Notification.bigContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView), the action buttons never show up.

Just to clarify, if I never set `bigContentView`, the buttons do show up. But as soon as that field is set to a custom RemoteViews object, the buttons are gone.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various `Big...Style` builders create their own `bigContentView`. If you want your own `bigContentView`, you have to add the buttons yourself, perhaps by examining [the source code to those builders](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Notification.java) and seeing how they do it.

Comment: Hey do you know perhaps where can I find the layout configurations for notifications? any XML file perhaps?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have not gone looking for those, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. Any guess where I should look for it?

Answer (score 1):

When you add your custom bigContentView it will replace the contentview that is created by Notification.BigPictureStyle, Notification.BigTextStyle or Notification.InboxStyle. As commonsware point out you need to add the button by yourself and thats by creating your own custom [remoteView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) with buttons and then add it as contentView.

You could find a tutorial of how to do this [here](http://feras.us/blog/custom-rich-notification-view-android/).