# Normal notification applies RemoteView, but BigPictureStyle doesn't

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have created a custom layout, which I use a RemoteView to apply the layout to my notification. Everything works fine.

Then, I also wanted to implement a BigPictureStyle to my notification, so when the user expand the notification, or when it's the first one, the notification gets bigger and can display more info/larger icons.

The problem is: when the notification is expanded, I cannot see the buttons I have on my custom layout (which does show when it is contracted).

My question is: how can my expanded notification have the same buttons?

Here's the code I use to set up my notifications:

```
Target mTarget;
    String url = mMyTracks.get(mCurrentTrack).getCoverImgs();

    Intent notificationIntent;
    notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TopTracksActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(MediaPlayerDialogFragment.TRACKS, mMyTracks);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MediaPlayerDialogFragment.TRACK_NUMBER, mCurrentTrack);

    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textSongName, track.getName());
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textArtistName, track.getArtist());

    // Create base notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContent(remoteView)
                    .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    //BigPicture notification style
    final NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(track.getName());
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(track.getArtist());

    mTarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
    };

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(url)
            .into(mTarget);

    // Build the notification
    builder.setStyle(bigPictureStyle);
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    // Get current track's image
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(url)
            .into(remoteView, R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, 2503, notification);

    startForeground(2503, notification);
```

Thanks! =]

Comment: Maybe you want this?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13340548/706833
hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although I was not able to find why the BigPictureStyle doesn't use the RemoteView (yet), I found a alternative solution: set actions to the builder. This will ONLY be displayed when the notification is expanded.

Here's what I added to my code, right before I set the style to my builder:

```
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous, "Previous", notificationPendingIntent);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", notificationPendingIntent);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", notificationPendingIntent);
```